# multiprocessing issue with Windows

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, spyder

When using multiprocessing with Windows, we must have  `if __name__ == '__main__':`. For example:

```
# Script1.py

import multiprocessing
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def square(self, i, return_jobs, x):
        i = x**2
        return_jobs[i] = i 

    def run(self):
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
            return_jobs = manager.dict()
            jobs = []
            for i in range(len(self.x)):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.square, args=(i, return_jobs , self.x[i]) )
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()
            for proc in jobs:
                print(proc)
                proc.join()
            print('result',return_jobs.values())

Test([2, 3]) .run()
```

This simple example script ran fine and return something like: `result [4, 9]`. However, if I have have a different script and import `Script1` and use `Test` then it won't work. That is,

```
# Script2.py

from Script1.py import Test 
class Test2(object):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        
    def run(self):
        z = Test(self.y).run()
```

will **not invoke** the function `Test(self.y).run()` at all. However, if I place the class `Test2` in the same script as `Test` (# Script1.py ) then all is fine.

**What is the best way to fix this?** The `Script1.py` is a subprocess of the overall code. I don't want to have to combine these scripts together...

I should also note that I am using **Spyder** as well. This could be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in *Script1.py*, where you have placed the `if __name__ == "__main__":` check is not the correct place. It should be placed as follows:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test([2, 3]) .run()
```

This is for two reasons. First, when the new processes are created, any statements at global scope will be executed by these processes. If you do not put the check as I have above, you will be needlessly creating instances of `Test` objects. It's true that when `run` is invoked against these objects `run` will immediately return because of where you did place the check, but why create the objects to begin with?

But the real reason for moving the check as I have done is that you only want to execute the statement `Test([2, 3]).run()` when you are executing *Script1.py* as the "main" script and not when it is being imported by some other script. By placing the check as I have done, when it is imported its name will *not* be "__main__" any more and therefore that statement will not be executed, which gives you more flexibility.

This now allows you in *Script2.py* to add your own `if __name__ == '__main__':` check as follows:

```py
from Script1 import Test

class Test2(object):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def run(self):
        z = Test(self.y).run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test2([3, 6]).run()
```

Prints:

```
<Process name='Process-2' pid=9200 parent=4492 started>
<Process name='Process-3' pid=16428 parent=4492 started>
result [9, 36]
```

So that when *Script2.py* is the "main" script being executed, you have control over what object gets created and run.

**Explanation**

The important thing to remember with Windows is that when a script launches a new process that process starts execution of the source from the top so all statements at global scope (import statements, function declarations, variable assignments, etc.) are executed. Thus you want to avoid having at global scope things that don't need to be there since they will be re-executed by the new process and you might be doing for instance a calculation or creation of a large data structure that the newly created process does not use and you have wasted CPU cycles or memory for nothing. But you absolutely must not have any statements at global scope that when executed end up re-creating recursively the process you just created. That is why we have the need for the `if __name__ == "__main__":` around such statements (`__name__` will not be "__main__" in the newly created process). So there is no need to have such a check in the `run` method, which is not at global scope. But eventually, in whatever script you run to starts things off, you *will* need that check for any code at global scope code that creates a process or invokes a function or method that creates a process.

Note that when *Script2.py* imports *Script1.py*, *Script1.py* is now a module and it's `__name__` value will be "Script1", and again the code `Test([2, 3]).run()` will not execute. So that also explains why when we create a module we can place testing code within an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block -- it will not be executed when the module is imported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). I understand your point about placing `if __name__ == "__main__":` outside the function `run`. It was actually what I did at first as well. The reason why I wrote it inside the function is because Script1.py is invoke by Script2.py through calling `Test.run()`.  Thus, if it was placed outside the class then it wouldn't that be a problem?  It seems like the problem is that I am using Spyder and Windows. Not sure though.

Comment: it has nothing to do with spyder or windows. It is caused by using "spawn" rather than "fork" as the method of starting a child process ("spawn" is your only option on windows, and is default on MacOS). The child process will `import` the main file to get access to all the necessary objects, so your "main" file shouldn't "do" anything if it's imported beyond import stuff and define stuff. `if __name__ == "__main__":` belongs in your "main" file (*Script2.py*)

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer that I hope answers your question.